# ¿Cómo enviar audio con la librería Libshout a shoutcast?

Tags: java

El siguiente código me va bien para enviar un audio en vivo hacia un servidor Icecast, podrían decirme como manipulo los datos o configuro para enviarlo a shoutcast ya que no tiene punto de montaje como, por ejemplo en icecast puedo tener "test.mp3" pero en shoutcast yo tengo ";", Además que esto solo en linux funciona, ¿cómo hago para compilarlo para windows?. [Libhsout Github](https://github.com/OlegKunitsyn/libshout-java)

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
InputStream mp3 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("test.mp3")));
Libshout icecast = new Libshout();
icecast.setHost("localhost");
icecast.setPort(8000);
icecast.setProtocol(Libshout.PROTOCOL_HTTP);
icecast.setPassword("hackme");
icecast.setMount("/mymount");
icecast.setFormat(Libshout.FORMAT_MP3);
icecast.open();
int read = mp3.read(buffer);
while (read > 0) {
    icecast.send(buffer, read);
    read = mp3.read(buffer);
}
icecast.close();
mp3.close();
```

Comment: Hola Maghdiel, en realidad este sitio no es para pedir recomendaciones o solicitar búsquedas. Para eso recomendamos Google. Si tienes algún problema al usar alguna solución de las que hayas encontrado, no dudes en hacer las preguntas necesarias, siempre siguiendo esta guía: __[mcve]__.

Comment: Bueno es que requiero transmitir desde java hacia shoutcast con o sin libreria pero no parece contestar nadie.

Comment: Así es Maghdiel. Esta comunidad no funciona cuando alguien pide recomendaciones, por eso no contestan. Preferimos preguntas concretas, por ejemplo: _"Tengo el error ABC cuando uso la librería FOO para hacer streaming en Java, he intentado B y C sin resultados. Este es un ejemplo de mi código"_